# K-means with weighed variables

Tags: r, statistics, k-means

I want to perform the K-means analysis where some of my variables should be considered more important than the others. I have found the kmeansw function, but after reading its help I am a bit confused:

> Usage
>
> kmeansW(x, centers, weight = rep(1,nrow(x)),
>           iter.max = 10, nstart = 1) Arguments
>
> x
>
> A numeric vector, matrix or data frame.
>
> centers
>
> Either the number of clusters or a set of initial (distinct) cluster
>   centres. If a number, a random set of (distinct) rows in x is chosen
>   as the initial centres.
>
> weight
>
> weight of the elements of x. by default the same.
>
> iter.max
>
> The maximum number of iterations allowed.
>
> nstart
>
> If centers is a number, how many random sets should be chosen?

Do I understand it right that it weighs elements of data frame (rows) and not variables (columns)? If this is right, what other way would you recommend for this problem?

Comment: Why not just transpose your matrix?

Comment: you can just duplicate as many times as needed the variables you want to increase weight

Comment: The function should weight variables differently. The k-means algorithm relies on euclidean distances between samples; the weighting should reflect how strong each variable value is considered when computing pairwise distances.

Comment: I guess you can't transpose because it will cluster variables and not observations

Comment: although if you're OK to use a different algo, `daisy` allow variable weights (package cluster). Daisy returns a dissimilarity matrix

Comment: @PejoPhylo is right, this is exactly what I need and as pointed above transposing is not going to give me proper results. Duplicating is also a bit problematic, because I have about 50 variables and I would split them into three groups of uneven amount of variables, therefore finding out of many times to duplicate each one seems very tedious.

Comment: @agenis I see daisy return dissimilarities, but I cannot find if it returns some clustering too, which is my main goal here.

Comment: @PrzeM, you should also be able to simply multiply each vector of interest by a constant number (corresponding to the weight). With this modified matrix, you can run a standard k-means algorithm.

Comment: @PrzeM Yes you're right, so you can run `pam` algo taking the diss. matrix as input. It should work. Pam is k-medoids, a "cousin" of kmeans

Comment: @PrzeM 's idea is probably the best and simpler. But maybe you should scale your data first, i guess (well, that's an old debate)

Comment: I will have a look at this function, thanks. For multiplicative approach, do I have to multiply variables by square root of weight? I have tried multiplying by weights directly but my Professor said this isn´t correct. Data is already scaled, by the way.

Comment: @PrzeM Hi any news on your distance calculation? What method did y choose? have you found the right multiplication factor?

Comment: Professor who is supervising my project told me to multiply the scaled values by their weights, not weights' square root like I have proposed to him. I am just going to stick to his decision as I still have some other problems to solve and very little time left to complete it.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply multiply your features by your desired weights "after scaling the data". This increases the euclidean distances of weighted features between your observations and consequently fulfills your requirement.

Comment: What a smart way... I will try it.